# Working with 2 tables PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a webpage that displays list of shops. I have 2 tables, `shops` and `shops_sched`.

```
+-shops-+
| id | title |

+-------------shops_sched-------------+
| id | shops_id | start_date | end_date |
```

Basically, the program displays the list of shops from the `shops` table, but if a value from `shops.id` is found @ `shops_sched.shops_id` the page must output `shops.title` + 'coming soon'.

I understand this will be easy if I just place the date fields inside the table `shops` but due to programming restrictions I can't. I'm working on an existing project and I'm trying to minimize changes to existing functions. I can create new PHP functions if necessary though.

In addition, I need to get all the entries from the shops table. The Program needs to return all shops.title but for those shops whose id is found @ shops_sched.shops_id, the program will have to return shops.title + "Coming Soon".

Comment: Search for `left outer join`, you will get plenty of information.

Comment: I can't use inner join, for it will only return the rows which id's are found at shops_sched.shop_id. I need to get all rows regardless whether its id is found at the shops_sched table or not.

Comment: The difference between an `inner join` and a `left outer join` is exactly, that the latter returns all rows of the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables :

```
SELECT shops.title
FROM shops INNER JOIN shops_sched ON shops.id = shops_sched.shops_id
```

The query should return only the the shops inside shops_sched

EDIT :

If I understood your question, try this :

```
SELECT shops.title, shops_sched.id
FROM shops LEFT JOIN shops_sched ON shops.id = shops_sched.shops_id
```

This will return all the titles, and the shops_sched.shops_id if shops.id = shops_sched.shops_id. In the other case, the hops_sched.shops_id will be null

Then you fetch the rows and if the second row is not null, print title + coming soon

Sample code : (Something like this)

```
$query = "SELECT `title`, 'shops_id' FROM `shops` LEFT JOIN `shops_sched` ON `shops`.`id`     = `shops_sched`.`shops_id` WHERE `shops_sched`.`shop_id`";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    if($row['shops_id'] != "")
    {
         echo $row['title'] . ' coming soon';
    }
    else
    {
         echo $row['title'];
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition, I need to get all the entries from the shops table. The Program needs to return all shops.title but for those shops whose id is found @ shops_sched.shops_id, the program will have to return shops.title + "Coming Soon".

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand you well.. You need all the tables from shops and if they are found in shops_sched, you want to return title + coming soon?

Comment: Yes I need all entries from shops, and if their id are found at shops_sched table, you will append "coming soon" to all entries affected. Ex I have 3 entries from shops table - 1- McDonalds, 2 - KFC and 3 - Burger King.  And @shops_sched table I have values 1 & 2 from the shop_id field. The program will have to return -- McDonalds (Coming Soon), KFC (Coming Soon), Buger King

Answer (score 0):

> must output shops.title + 'coming soon'.

So do it like this:

```
$shops.title = "Donut-John";
echo $shops.title." coming soon";
```

Answer (score 0):

To join the shops and shops_sched table

```
$query = SELECT `title` FROM `shops` JOIN `shops_sched` ON `shops`.`id` = `shops_sched`.`shops_id` WHERE `shops_sched`.`shop_id` = 5;

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    echo $row['title'] . 'coming soon';
}
```

For more about join you also can refer the following link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm